# iPhone FBConnect when password has changed

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I was testing for a bug found by a tester when I ran across this.  I think it's a FBConnect bug but I thought I would try here to see if anyone else has had this issue:

I've FBConnected from the iPhone app to FB, logged in correctly and verified that I can resume the session. Then, I go to FB and change my password.  The next time I try to post a link to FB from the iPhone app. the FBStreamingDialog shows up but disappears immediately.  Upon debugging, the window is "cancelled" (the delegate is not getting called which is strange) and the return url from the webView inside FBDialog is "fbconnect:success"

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

-Don

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with the Facebook API but the "fbconnect:success" looks more like an objective-C selector instead of a URL. That suggest you may have a method call somehow confused with a string representing the URL. This sometimes happens when you send a selector as part of a notification.

Just a wild guess.

Comment: Actually, I was able to get around this by shooing a FBRequest out and waiting for either: didLoad or didFailWithError from the request.